# Angular4 Reactive nested form issue

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms

I am using Angular 4 reactive to create nested forms.My forms structures like below

- Form Group(userform)
- FormArray(users)
- FormGroup(idx)

In complete **table** come under **Form Group** and each **table row** come under **FormArray(users)** and each **table data** cells come under Formgroup(idx).

**Error:**

```
appComponent.html:20 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'users -> 0 -> '
```

**HTML:**

```
<form [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()">
    <tbody formArrayName="users">
        <tr *ngFor="let user of users.controls; index as idx">
            <div [formGroupName]="idx">
          <td>
            <div class="mdl-select mdl-js-select mdl-select--floating-label">
            <select class="mdl-select__input" id="projectname{{i}}" name="projectname{{i}}"  [formControlName]="projectname">
              <option *ngFor="let project of projects;let first=first;let last:last">{{project.projectname}}</option>
            </select>
            <label class="mdl-select__label" for="professsion">Select Project Name</label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
              <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" id="sunday{{i}}" name="sunday{{i}}"  [formControlName]="sunday">
              <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Digits only</span>
            </div>
          </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

**TS:**

```
export class appComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  userForm = new FormGroup({

      users: new FormArray([
               new FormControl()
            ])
      });

      get userName(): any {
        return this.userForm.get('name');
      }
      onFormSubmit(): void {
        this.logData();
      }
      get users(): FormArray { 
        return this.userForm.get('users') as FormArray; 
      }
      addUserField() { 
        this.users.push(new FormControl()); 
      }
      deleteUserField(index: number) {
        this.users.removeAt(index);
      }

      logData(){
        for(let i = 0; i < this.users.length; i++) {
          console.log(this.users.at(i).value);
        }
      }

    }
```

Comment: Well quickly looking at your code, we can at least determine that you are trying to display a formcontrol named `projectname` in template even though there is no such form control in your form :) Same goes for the form control `sunday`.

Comment: Giving index value for formcontrol ,  i am getting only last input table data input element

Comment: I didn't quite get the comment. But anyway, the form controls in template must match the form control in form, and right now they do not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your form controls do not match your template. Right now in your `users` array you just have one unspecified form control. Instead you should have the two form controls that you are displaying in the template. Assumingly you want an initial empty form group in your array, do:

```ts
this.userForm = this.fb.group({
  users: this.fb.array([
    this.initUsers();
  ])
});

initUsers() {
  return this.fb.group({
    projectname: [''],
    sunday: ['']
  });
}
```

where `fb` refers to `FormBuilder` injected in constructor.

With the above you now have the two form controls in your form array. You also call `initUsers()` when you want to add a new form group (row) in your table.

Then you need to remove the brackets around `formcontrolName` in your template, so instead of

```ts
[formControlName]="projectname"
....
[formControlName]="sunday"
```

do:

```ts
formControlName="projectname"
...
formControlName="sunday"
```

DEMO: http://plnkr.co/edit/qraDXUYOaOL9eClTqjqh?p=preview

Also worth mentioning, I see you have a `pattern` validation for `sunday` in **template**, remove that and set the `Validators.pattern()` instead for your form control.

Comment: same structure but i want  to add and remove button each in each  table data inside row .If user click add button i need to create another table row

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Just set a button for add and delete and do the appropriate methods for that :)

Comment: i cant able to retrieved formGroup data after submit the form

Comment: Works fine here, when console logged after clicking button.... http://plnkr.co/edit/qraDXUYOaOL9eClTqjqh?p=preview

Comment: when user click on AddRow button one more tr will created and contains same dropdown and input box and AddRow and DeleteRow input elements are there . When ever user click on AddRow Button it create same table row . Ones user stop create table row and enter data from all the columns and click submit button i cant able to retrive data. it is my issue

Comment: All works fine here. Compare your code to this: http://plnkr.co/edit/l2ozc2KajILg5Hw7rWCw?p=preview If you don't get your code to work, please recreate the issue in plunker, and I'll take a look.